# Posting another web query during render_GET or render_POST processing

Tags: twisted

I have a small web server written using Twisted. One of the things I want to do is have it return a result from another web server as the response to loading a page. That is, the response to render_GET() at server A (via http://A.com/resource) should be the content of a different URL at server B (via http://B.com/resource2). The content returned by server B is dynamic, so I can't just cache it.

Right now, server A can render pages just fine, it just can't render this remote resource. I've tried with Agent(), but I can't seem to get the response from B let alone forward it to A. I know that somewhere I have to take that request from the render_GET and later `write()` and `finish()` it. That's done in the `cbBody` callback, which get called but can't get to the original request to populate it.

Here's a piece of the code for server A's resource handler:

```
def render_GET(self,request):
    # try with canned content just to test the whole thing
    bmpServer = BMPServer(ServerBURL,
                          "xyzzy",
                          "plugh")
    d= bmpServer.postNotification({"a":123},request)
    print "Deferred", d
    return NOT_DONE_YET
```

And this is the other code at server A:

```
theRequest = None

def cbRequest(response,args):
    print "response called"
    print response
    print args
    print 'Response version:', response.version
    print 'Response code:', response.code
    print 'Response phrase:', response.phrase
    print 'Response headers:'
    print pformat(list(response.headers.getAllRawHeaders()))  
    d = readBody(response)
    d.addCallback(cbBody)
    return d

def cbBody(body):
    print "Response body:"
    print body
    theRequest.write(body)
    theRequest.finish()
    theRequest = None

def cbError(failure):
    print type(failure.value), failure # catch error here
    print failure.value.reasons[0].printTraceback()

class BMPServer(object):
    def __init__(self,url,arg1,arg2):
        self.url = url
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def postNotification(self,message,request):
        theRequest = request
        bmpMessage = {'arg1':self.token,
                      'arg2':self.appID,
                      'message':message}
        print "Sending request to %s"%self.url

        print "Create agent"
        agent = Agent(reactor)
        print "create request deferred"
        print "url = %s" % self.url
        d = agent.request('POST', self.url,
                          Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
                          MessageProducer(bmpMessage))
        print "adding callback"
        d.addCallbacks(cbRequest,cbError)
        print "returning deferred"
        return d
```

When I run this as a standalone code (outside of the resource, using `react()` for example), it works fine. However, when I try to include it as shown above it just never seems to receive the data. I've got WireShark running so I can see the response is being returned from Server B, but the data never shows up in `cbRequest()`.

For example, here's the output I see:

```
Sending request to http://localhost:8888/postMGCMNotificationService
Create agent
create request deferred
url = http://serverB:8888/postService
Message producer: body = {"arg2": "plugh", "arg1": "xyzzy", "message": {"a": 1}}
adding callback
returning deferred
testAgent: returning deferred
<Deferred at 0x10b54d290>
Writing body now
response called
<twisted.web._newclient.Response object at 0x1080753d0>
Response version: ('HTTP', 1, 1)
Response code: 200
Response phrase: OK
Response headers:
Response body:
{"result": false}
^CUnhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0_r39314-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 1151, in _bodyDataFinished_CONNECTED
    self._bodyProtocol.connectionLost(reason)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0_r39314-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/twisted/web/client.py", line 1793, in connectionLost
    self.deferred.callback(b''.join(self.dataBuffer))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0_r39314-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 382, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0_r39314-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0_r39314-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "AServer.py", line 85, in cbBody
    print theRequest
exceptions.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'theRequest' referenced before assignment
```

Looking at this a little more, it seems that if I could figure out a way to get the request over to `cbBody()` this would all work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass extra arguments to callbacks on a `Deferred`:

```
d.addCallback(f, x)
```

When d fires, the result is `f(result of d, x)`.  You can pass as many positional or keyword arguments as you like this way.  See [the API documentation for `Deferred`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! I changed the signature of cbResponse and cbBody to include a request parameter, and changed the addCallback from `addCallback(cbResponse)` to `addCallback(cbResponse,request)` and now the response comes perfectly.

Comment: For the record, I did read the documentation but I couldn't understand what it meant - if it were a C function it would make sense to me but my native language isn't Python so I didn't quite grok it.